# Extract words from file using separate word list

Tags: bash, awk

I have a text file containing a list of strings, for example `a.txt`

```
one
two
three
```

I also have another text file containing a list of strings, for example `b.txt`

```
threetwo
onetwothree
zero
twozero
```

What I wish to do is compare the two and find whether any of the fields inside `b.txt` contain fields from `a.txt`

Example of output in this case would be,

```
threetwo > two, three
onetwothree > one, two, three
twozero > two
```

If my explanation wasn't explanatory enough then I have this written in C# which will produce my expectations.

```
List<string> allElements = new List<string> { "one", "two", "three" };
string str = "onetwothree";
var containingElements = allElements.Where(element => str.Contains(element));
foreach(string element in containingElements)
{
    Console.WriteLine(element);
}
```

you can run the above code on `dotnetfiddle.net`

I would prefer this to be achieved using awk, any help would be appreciated :).

Comment: Hello and welcome!  Would you mind editing your post and showing us what you've attempted so far?

Comment: @DanielWalker to be honest I haven't attempted anything, I'm not sure where to begin.. was just looking for some direction

Comment: Why awk? If I understand the requirement correctly, `grep -f a.txt b.txt` finds whether any of the fields inside b.txt contain fields from a.txt.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the return value of awk's `index` function to determine whether a line in `b.txt` contains a substring from `a.txt`.

> ```
> index(in, find)
>
>     Search the string in for the first occurrence of the string find, and return 
> the position in characters where that occurrence begins in the string in.
> ```

For example:

```
awk '
  NR==FNR{strings[$1]; next}
  {
    m = ""
    for(s in strings){
      if(index($0,s) > 0) m = (m=="") ? s : m ", " s
    }
  }
  m != "" {print $0, ">", m}
' a.txt b.txt
threetwo > three, two
onetwothree > three, two, one
twozero > two
```

Note that array traversal order (in this case, the array of substrings constructed from `a.txt`) is not guaranteed in awk.